# Sencha touch getView() in controller is undefined

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i follow [this](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/) tutorial to learn sencha touch 2. in chapter 3 when i want to active second view, it's undefined:

```
var newPage = this.getNewPageContainer();
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(newPage, this.slideRightTransition); // noting happend.

console.log(this.getNewChallangeContainer()); // print "undefined"
```

i also set it on config, refs:

```
refs: {
   // We're going to lookup our views by xtype.
   pagecontainer: "pagecontainer",
   newPageContainer: "newpagecontainer"
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you add your view to the views array in the app.js file as noted in the Making the Application Aware of the View section in the tutorial?

Comment: Couple of things - Did you define slideRightTransition  in the config section.  Did you define a ref for newChallangeContainer ? i notice you are trying to print it but it is not in your refs section.  Can you post your full code?